# Why this image is loaded from right to left?

Tags: image, load

You can see it in Chrome: http://toliklunev.ru/image.jpg

Image, resaved by Photoshop, is loaded normally: http://toliklunev.ru/image2.jpg

Why?

UPD:
In Firefox everything is much more interesting. The first image is turned.

Comment: If I zoom in and out on the first image, it displays correctly. This looks like a bug in Chrome that misscales rotated images. I can't see what you mean by "right to left", however.

Comment: @JanDvorak: The first image is loaded from right to left, and the second from top to bottom. Normally images are loaded from top to bottom. You can watch it clearly on slow internet connection.

Comment: ah, I thought you were complaining about the weird aspect ratio. The order of loading is merely defined by how the image is saved.

Comment: How to save image like this? And why in Firefox first image is turned?

Comment: chrome is using EXIF data (orientation="6") in first image and autorotating it. It loads from top so top is on right now ...

Comment: The image links in your question are dead. Please consider using a regular image hosting site in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a look at the EXIF data of your image:

```
Color Space sRGB
Exif Image Size 2,592 × 1,936
Orientation Rotate 90 CW
```

As an non-progressive (baseline) JPEG, it is being loaded top-down. However, Google Chrome takes the rotation parameter into account and rotates the file in the first place, thus it seems to be loaded right-left.